# How can do an invariant .Contains(myQuery) with Linq to Objects?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to filter a list of objects using linq. When i filter by a `Contains(someSearchQuery)` it's like it's being case sensitive .. meaning i miss some results.

---

I have an `IList<Foo>`'s which has a number of properties, but one is `public string MyText { get; set; }`

Now, i'm trying to return a IQueryable of Foo's where the MyText property contain the `search query` - but as a  If this was a Sql statement, it would be either..

`WHERE MyText LIKE '%searchQuery%'` <-- Works but inefficent

or

`WHERE CONTAINS(MyText, 'searchQuery')` <-- using FTS.

I'm not sure how to do this, because when I do the following query it's like it's doing a case sensitive

`var query = from q in myFooList.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.MyText.Contains(searchQuery));`

Suggestions?

Comment: ToUpper/ToLower on both searchQuery and MyText would do the trick.

Comment: @klausbyskov initially I thought of that too .. and yep. that did work .. but it felt like it's *just not right* / *smells wrong* or something....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking about the `string.Contains` method, not about LINQ.

`String.Contains` does not support case-insensitive searching.  Instead, you should call `IndexOf`, like this:

```
var query = from q in myFooList
     .Where(x => x.MyText.IndexOf(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Note that since you're using LINQ-to-Objects, you (presumably) don't need `AsQueryable`.

Comment: tha man! That works beautifully :) Out of interest, would this also work for Linq-To-Sql/Entities?

Comment: I don't know, but i would suspect not.